# Controlling the Sound of Audio

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, audio

I am playing the sound in my App and sound still continue play even when App enter into background i want to control the Volume of that audio when it enter into background . Like in this APP [example](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-my-phone/id485660002?mt=8).I want audio volume remain maximum even user try to turn off the volume. I am unable to splve it can any one out there help me out.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using AVAudioPlayer the just use AVAudioPlayer instance say player like this:

```
   player.volume=1; //for maximum volume
```

This is AVAudioPlayer's volume, and in reply to your question that even if user minimizes volume of Iphone it should remain in full, then you should know that according to apple policies, there are things which have control for user only, this is what they call user privilege, your app can not control iphone volume,

and for controlling player volume (you don't need any effort if you talk about iphone volume) , i am little doubtful how you want to do this, i mean you must have some button or horizontal slider to achieve this, anyhow proceed with your logic with the delegate method

```
   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

in your appdelegate class

Comment: Thank you Najeebullah Shah for you response please check this [App](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-my-phone/id485660002?mt=8) i want to i implement the same functionality like in this App but the only functionality which is remaining in implementation is that "Audio will contine even user try to turn off the Volume"

Comment: by Volume do you mean iphone volume or player Volume

Comment: iPhone Volume , because if user low the volume of iPhone/iPad the Player Volume will automatically will become low